# How to return an Excel workbook from a web service

Tags: service, excel-2007

I was asked to create a web service that would be called from a macro in an Excel workbook. The reason behind that is because we have a web application that returns reports in Excel format to the users (and there are several different reports), but some of the reports take a long time to generate – even to execute the stored procedure on the SQL Server. So this web service is to be used to short-cut the long-running process in the web application.
My problem is understanding how the web service would return the workbook - can that be done without using XML/XSD?
Someone tried using the CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter in the application previously, but never got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use XML, you could probably just send it back as a base 64 encoded byte array.  You'd just need to write another macro to decode it and write it to a file, I suppose.